# Unable to Start t-sql debugging

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am using remote desktop, logging directly onto the box that houses the sql instance, and trying to use debugging, however getting the dreaded unable to start t-sql debugging... error message.

My colleague can take the same steps, same box, and using the same sql account and has no issue, the only difference is we are using our own windows accounts, which when checked both of us are part of the local admin group.

we are both logging on as the instance name also. SSMS 2014.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you gone through all the suggestions on page 1 of Google when searching "Unable to Start tsql debugging" and found them all to not work?

Comment: Yes I have. thanks for asking though

Comment: What is the error message (please quote exact wording)?